# GWT : null stack

Tags: javascript, gwt, gwt-rpc

I get this exception every time when I want do some operation.

```
(TypeError): b.k.g.E is null stack: TBe([object Object]) ....
```

How can I correct it?

Comment: Can you give more details? Examples of the code you are using?

Comment: Which part of code? Code is very big. This exception occurs when I am get a response from the RPC. The RPC returned class has 26 fields & some of them null. It is interesting that in development mode all OK, there is no exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the message should be read as *"X is null"* and *"stack: ..."*, not *"null stack"*.

You can "deobfuscate" what `TBe` means by looking at the `symbolMap` generated by GWT (by default in `WEB-INF/deploy`): find the `symbolMap` file corresponding to the permutation your browser is loading (the `symbolMap` file name is the same as the `cache.html` file loaded by your browser) and then search for `TBe` within it (case sensitive!), and it'll give you the corresponding method in your Java code. That might give you a hint as to what could be null.

Also, if you use Chrome, you can *pretty-print* the JS code in the Dev Tools, which allows you to easily debug the code: set a breakpoint in the `TBe` function and debug, step-by-step, inspecting variables, etc. Just as you do in Java within Eclipse (or whichever your IDE).

Note that GWT 2.5 will generate `SourceMaps` which will allow you to see and "debug" your Java code from within your browser! Screenshot [here](https://plus.google.com/110412141990454266397/posts/iqXo5AyHkyd), and design doc [there](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/SourceMaps).